# web2py: multiple forms on one page

Tags: forms, web2py, multiple-forms

I am trying to make a form which shows all products from a group in a list. They can be given a quantity and added to a quote. Which is then stored in the database.

None of the automagical form options are working for me. So I've made each row showing information for a given product with the Quantity box and an add item button it's own form. But the loop which makes each form is doing something strange.

Controller:

```
products = db(db.product.group_id == productgroupnumber).select()
forms=[]
for product in products:
    form = FORM(TABLE(TR(TD(product.productname),
                         TD((product.purchasecost or 0)),
                         TD((product.monthlycost or 0)),
                         TD(INPUT(_type='number', _name='quantity')),
                         TD(INPUT(_type='submit', _value=T('Add to Offer')))
                         )
                      )
                )
    forms.append(form)

session.quotedproducts = []
if form.accepts(request, session, keepvalues = True):
    product = db(db.product.id == product_id).select().first()
    offeritem = [product_id, request.vars.quantity, product.purchasecost, product.monthlycost]
    session.quotedproducts.append(offeritem)
    response.flash = T("Item added to offer")`
```

For 2 rows. The View has the below 2 forms, with only one hidden div with the formkey and formname. So I can't name the forms in order to process them properly:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Block of 10 Phone Numbers</td>
           <td>19.0</td>
           <td>0</td>
           <td><input name="quantity" type="number" /></td>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Add to Offer" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>     

<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>100 Block of Phone Numbers</td>
            <td>149.0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><input name="quantity" type="number" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add to Offer" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<!--Why is there only one of these??--> 
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="b99bea37-f107-47f0-9b1b-9033c15e1193" />
        <input name="_formname" type="hidden" value="default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I give the forms individual names (preferably product.id)?
I tried adding the formname argument:

```
form.accepts(request, session, formname=product.id)
```

But this only names one form and the other is still named 'Default'.

Comment: Should the user be able to submit multiple forms at the same time, or will a single submission include only a single form?

Comment: Only a single form. So a row has a quantity field and an 'Add to Quote' button. Only product can be added at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you create multiple forms in the `for` loop, but after exiting the loop, you call `form.accepts()`. At that point, the value of `form` is the last form created in the loop, so only that form is processed.

Note, when a form is initially created, the `form.accepts` (or the preferred `form.process`) method adds the `_formname` and `_formkey` hidden fields to the form (these are used for CSRF protection). When that same method is called after form submission, it additionally handles form validation. So, given your workflow, you must process all the forms both at creation and submission. Maybe something like this:

```
products = db(db.product.group_id == productgroupnumber).select()
forms = []
for product in products:
    quantity_name = 'quantity_%s' % product.id
    form = FORM(TABLE(TR(TD(product.productname),
                         TD((product.purchasecost or 0)),
                         TD((product.monthlycost or 0)),
                         TD(INPUT(_type='number', _name=quantity_name)),
                         TD(INPUT(_type='submit', _value=T('Add to Offer')))
                         )
                      )
                )
    if form.process(formname=product.id, keepvalues=True).accepted:
        offeritem = [product.id, form.vars[quantity_name],
                     product.purchasecost, product.monthlycost]
        session.quotedproducts.append(offeritem)
        response.flash = T("Item added to offer")
    forms.append(form)
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you, that answers the question.

Comment: You mentioned processing the forms at submission also. I have the forms named. But as the 'Form' variable only exists in the scope of the creation loop. How do I process them again at submission?

Comment: The forms are submitted to the same action that generates them, so the same code processes the submissions. When `form.process()` is called at creation time, it generates the hidden `_formname` and `_formkey` fields for the form. When that same method is called at submission time, it checks the `_formkey` field and validates the form.